# C# trying to extract the primary keys associated to my object from the dB

Tags: c#, database, linq, rest-client, object-properties

I want to store the primary key to a property of my object called dBID. Currently using a RestClient to get data from my db but I'm not too sure how I am to be able to return the DbSet of primary keys and get them to match like they do on the dB. So for example I have this get function that currently returns all of the elements in this table.

```
    // GET: api/ObjectX
    public IQueryable<ObjectX> GetObjectX()
    {
       return dB.ObjectX
    }
```

What I want to do is make a similar query to return the primary keys which can be accessed through for example a .id in the server side, to my object property list on the client side.

Comment: just... use EntityFramework ...

Comment: thats what I have right now but can you go further on your idea I don't understand

Comment: SELECT Id FROM MyTable WHERE {condition}...done

Comment: I can't use that in my case

Comment: [Basic LINQ Query Operations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397927.aspx) - look at _Selecting (Projections)_